# Mongodb timeseries support data ingested from debezium

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, debezium

I have multiple devices which generates data using their sensors and send to my sever. On the server side telemetry data saved in json format in the postgresql database. Sensors data saved in a partitioned table(named `statuses`) which partitioned on `time_stamp` monthly and `device_id`. Also device info saved in a regular table (named `devices`).

As an example of status data of two months we have:

```
statuses_p2023_06
time_stamp                   | device_id | status
2023-06-21 06:17:46.409+00   |    2      | {"humidity": "17", "wind":"14"}
2023-06-21 06:15:46.409+00   |    1      | {"temperature": "22", "wind":"14"} 
2023-06-21 06:15:26.409+00   |    2      | {"humidity": "15", "wind": "12"}
2023-06-21 06:13:46.409+00   |    1      | {"temperature": "23", "humidity":"9"}
.
.
.
```

```
statuses_p2023_07
time_stamp                   | device_id | status
2023-07-11 08:17:46.409+00   |    1      | {"temperature": "23", "humidity":"9"}
2023-07-11 08:15:46.409+00   |    1      | {"temperature": "24"} 
2023-07-11 08:15:26.409+00   |    2      | {"humidity": "10", "wind":"11"}
2023-07-11 08:13:46.409+00   |    1      | {"wind": "12"}
```

Since there is frequent queries like `SELECT * FROM statuses WHERE time_stamp > '2023-07-01' and device_id=1 and status->>'temperature' > 22;` we must could search in json data efficiently. But as we know search on json data in postgresql is not very efficient(i.e I could not create index in on every property). So I used debezium as a CDC tool to transform data from postgresql to mongodb in order to search in json data. Debezium aggregates partitioned `statuses` data into a single table and save on the mongodb. So now I could search more effiecienlty in the status data of devices but what about partitioning of data in the long time?

The problem is Debezium transformed data with `upsert` write policy and mongodb timeseries does [not support](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/#updates-and-deletes) `upsert`.

Is there any way to change debezium write policy or handle partitioning with `upsert` in mongodb?

Comment: About the PostgreSQL part: 1. If most or even all possible keys that can appear in the `status` json field are known, you could set up a column for each, or apply [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Then, set up regular b-tree indexes on those. 2. *"search on json data in postgresql is not very efficient(i.e I could not create index in on every property)"* - Have you considered [`jsonb` with a GIN expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)?

Comment: @Zegarek Thanks. No parameters are not known and could be added in progress of time.

Comment: **1.** You don't need to know *all* the params that can possibly appear in the `status` field, you only need the most common while those less common or completely new can stay as they are. Most common as in most often queried about. **2.** I'm still not sure if the performance problems your question refers to, ones that pushed you to reach for debezium and mongo, you got from plain `json` type, or [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) I asked about earlier.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to "change" Debezium "write policy". Even if there would be a switch for changing the "write policy", MongoDB still could not upsert time series data.

There is no way to handle partitioning with `upsert` in MongoDB, as you pointed out.

Seems like searching with MongoDB has solved your search performance problem. If your partitioning of data in the "long time" means performance is not the focus anymore, you should `upsert` your time series data in [PostgreSQL with `INSERT ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)